# Updating Singleton

Tags: iphone, objective-c, singleton

In my application I have a singleton class for centrally storing my application data. I also load and save the objects here using nskeyarchiver. I have a management class where I create a series of numbersequencer instances initialized with the sequenceCollection from the Singleton class. If I modify  self.sequence and self.times stored within each of the evntSequencer dicts within my instances the values changed here are reflected in the source sequenceCollection stored in the Singleton. I can save using NSkeyArchiver and the values written are correct. If however I change the values by calling the loadProjectWithName method in the Singleton the source sequenceCollection is changed however the evntSequencers and the self.sequence and self.times within the numbersequencer instances are not updated and contain different values. I have got around this by adding the updateSequence method within my Management class. This all works but Its not particularly elegant and Im slightly confused to why I need to take this step?

SINGLETON CLASS

```
+(AppManager *)SharedAppManager{

    static AppManager *_sharedAppManager;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
    _sharedTileManager = [[self alloc]init];
    });

    return _sharedAppManager;

    }



+(id)alloc
    {
   {
        NSAssert(_sharedAppManager == nil,@"Attempted to allocate a second instance of the  
        singleton");
        _sharedAppManager = [super alloc];
        return _sharedAppManager;
     }

   }



-(id)init
{
   self = [super init];
   if (self) 
     {
    return self;
}

-(NSMutableDictionary *)collateProject {

    NSMutableDictionary *projectDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                self.sequenceCollection,@"sequences",nil];
    // other project container not shown

    return projectDict;

    } 



-(void)allocateSequencerStorage:(NSInteger)no {

      if (self.sequenceCollection ==nil) {

        self.sequenceCollection = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
        for (int i = 0; i < no; i++) {

        NSMutableArray *events = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        NSMutableArray *eventTimes = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        NSMutableDictionary *sequence = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:
        events,@"events",eventTimes,@"eventtimes", nil];

        [events release];
        [eventTimes release];

        [self.sequenceCollection setObject:sequence forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"sequence%d",i]];

        [sequence release];
     }

    }

    }

//File Manager class not shown

-(void)loadProjectWithName:(NSString *)name {

    id object = [FileManager loadFileWithName:name andPathID:kProjectFolder];
           if ([object isKindOfClass:[NSMutableDictionary class]]) {
              NSMutableDictionary *loadProject = object;

             //
            // SEQUENCES

                if ([loadProject objectForKey:@"sequences"] != nil) {        
                    self.sequenceCollection = [loadProject objectForKey:@"sequences"];

             //notify loaded

       }
```

MANAGEMENT CLASS  for managing the number sequencers other code not shown

```
#define AppSingleton ((AppManager*)[AppManager sharedAppManager])

-(id)initWithNo:(unsigned int)seqcount andMaxChainLen:(unsigned int)length {

    self = [super init];
    if (self) {

        //create our suite of sequencers
        self.sequencers = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

        // initiate central stores in singleton
        [AppSingleton allocateSequencerStorage:seqcount];

        for (int i = 0; i < seqcount; i++) {

            [self.sequencers addObject:[[NumberSequence alloc]initForSequenceWithLen:length   
     andTag:i withStore:AppSingleton.sequenceCollection]];

     [(NumberSequence*)[self.sequencers objectAtIndex:i]setDelegate:self];
        }
    }
    return self;
}

//This is called after sequenceCollection is updated in Singleton

-(void)updateSequences:(NSNotification *)notification {


    [self.sequencers enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) 
      {

            if ([obj isKindOfClass:[NumberSequence class]]) {

            NumberSequence *seq = obj;
           seq.evnts = [AppSingleton.numberCollection objectForKey:[NSString    
           stringWithFormat:@"sequence%d",idx]];
           seq.sequence = [seq.evnt objectForKey:@"events"];
           seq.times = [seq.evnts objectForKey:@"eventTimes"];

       }
      }];

     }
```

NUMBER SEQUENCE CLASS  other methods not shown

```
- (id)initForSequenceWithLen:(unsigned int)seqlen andTag:(unsigned int)tag withStore:   
(NSMutableDictionary *)store {

    if (self = [super init]){
        self.evntSequencer = store;
        self.sequence = [self.evntSequencer objectForKey:@"events"];
        self.times = [self.evntSequencer objectForKey:@"eventTimes"];
    }
    return self;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is OK: if your manager duplicates the data from your singleton class, there is no other way around as telling the manager to update is copy of the data when the original changes.

What you could do to improve things from a design perspective is having the `loadProjectWithName` method itself send the notification to its "clients" (e.g., the manager), so they know they have to update their local copy of the data.

I hope I have not misunderstood anything.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Sergio, I already have the loadProjectWithName method send the notifications it just isnt included int the code above.